# Angular.js: Dynamically add or remove directives from template based on state configuration

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angularjs app using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). The main purpose of the app is to search a family tree for people that meet specific criteria. I want to have different pre-configured scenarios, such as searching for data problems. Each scenario has a set of shared options that limit the extent of the search (how far from the starting person should we look). The scenarios also have options relevant only to that scenario or relevant to a subset of all scenarios. Options usually take the form of form elements like selects, checkboxes, and radio buttons. In the case of searching for data problems, we show a list of all problems we look for with checkboxes to turn the problem on or off. Each option (or group of options) has an associated directive and controller.

I'm trying to set this up so that all scenarios share the same template but different routes. That would require dynamically enabling/disabling the proper options with their associated directives and controllers.

I have the basics (a shared template but not configurable options) working with an abstract state.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){

  $stateProvider
    .state('search', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/search',
      templateUrl: 'searchPage.html'
    })
    .state('search.scenario1', {
      url: 'scenario1',
      controller: 'searchController'
    })
    .state('search.scenario2', {
      url: 'scenario2',
      controller: 'searchController'
    })

})
```

What I'm not sure about is the best way to dynamically turn on and off the options that are shown for a given scenario. I can think of two possibilities, but I'm not sure which is best nor if there's a better way. I prefer an option that allows me to add a new scenario by just setting up a new state. So it might look like this:

```
.state('search.scenario2', {
  url: 'scenario2',
  controller: 'searchController',
  data: {
    option1: true,
    optionGroup2: true
  }
})
```

I can't just use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` because the controllers will still be instantiated and affect the search with their default functionality even if they aren't shown.

#### 1. Have each controller look for a disabled attribute and do nothing if the attribute is present.

This seems like the easiest (less magic) but I would rather not let the controller be instantiated in the first place. It just feels wrong. I also don't like the idea of repeating the same logic in all of the controllers. Perhaps you know of a clean way to do this.

#### 2. Use the compile function of a parent directive to remove or insert the proper directives

I like this because I can assure that controllers are not unnecessarily instantiated but this method is not very straightforward. I'm not confident that I can correctly pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I thought of a third method for accomplishing this. Though it doesn't use state data as I had desired, it is very easy.

It uses [nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views). In the parent abstract template a define a view that the child scenarios will fill with a nested template. In those templates I include the directives for the relevant options. So a child state would look like this:

```
.state('search.scenario2', {
  url: 'scenario2',
  controller: 'searchController',
  templateUrl: 'scenario2.html'
})
```

Again, this doesn't use state data and it requires the creation of a template file for each scenario, but it's easy.